# Algorithm to find maximum sum of elements array such that not more than k elements are adjacent

Tags: c, algorithm

---

Hi,
  I came across this question. Given an array containing only positive values. You need to find the maximum sum that could result by adding the elements. The condition is that you cannot pick more than k adjacent elements. My simple solution is this

---

http://pastebin.com/s4KxjQRN

---

This solution does not produce correct input in all cases. I am not able to figure out why.
Can any one help? Thank you.

Comment: I found out the numbers that are at a distance of k and produce the minimum sum. Then I just subtracted this minimum sum from the total sum. This is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you just skip on every `k+1`th element. Sometimes, it's better to skip on more elements, but do it wisely. (choose the lowest numbers to skip on, etc)

Edit: some simple recursive solution: (it's not effective, but will work)

```
long maxsum(int n,int k,long *profits) {
    long sum=0,max=0,cur;
    int i;
    if (n<=k) {
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) sum+=profits[i];
        return sum;
    }
    for (i=0;i<=k;i++) {
        cur=sum+maxsum(n-i-1,k,profits+i+1);
        if (cur>max) max=cur;
        sum+=profits[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: I noticed we can store the max sum returned at each index  for finding the max value of next index. here is what i tried..

Comment: I noticed that max value up to each index can be stored and used for calculating max values of others.This is what I did.. http://pastebin.com/zJ36YmLg but this is not fast enough.. Any ideas